# How to create atomic POJO in java to handle thread safety?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Under the package `java.util.concurrent.atomic` there are several classes like `AtomicInteger, AtomicBoolean` etc. to handle thread safety.

How can I create my POJO that has the same atomic properties to handle thread safety? Is this a bad practice to make POJO atomic?

Are we supposed to use atomic fields in the POJO instead of atomic POJO?

The atomic classes do not implement or extend any `Atomic` interface or class, rather each of them has its own implementation. So if I want to define my `AtomicPojo` do I have to implement the same methods, or is there any third-party interface/class that can help me regarding this?

Comment: why not to add synchronised setters in the POJO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there is an AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater class under the J.U.C package, you can use an instance of AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater to update object properties and it is thread-safe.
Integer and Long data types can use AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater and AtomicLongFieldUpdater.

Define your POJO class

```
public class UserPojo {
  volatile String userName;
  volatile String password;
  
  public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
  }
  
  public void setUserName(String userName){
    this.userName = userName;
  }
  
  public String getUserName(){
    return this.userName;
  }
  
  public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
  }
}
```

Test

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    //create updater
    final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<UserPojo, String> updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(UserPojo.class, String.class, "userName");
    //UserPojo instance
    UserPojo user = new UserPojo();
    String userName = "vickllny";
    user.setUserName(userName);
    //10 threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int count = i;
        new Thread(() -> {
            //cas update
            updater.compareAndSet(user, userName, userName + count);
        }).start();
    }
 
    //Wait for the thread to finish executing
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do we need to use both updater and volatile keyword same time?

Comment: Yes, because the volatile keyword is required to ensure visibility to other threads